# Making a VM think a mouse is moving

Tags: azure, batch-file, cmd, vbscript, vmware

I am looking to use a VMware Horizon VM that goes into suspend mode after approximately a hour as a on-prem gateway for a couple of Azure applications I have built out. I do not want to change the power policy on the pool the VM is in. My thought is to build a VB Script that would simulate a mouse movement/key stroke every 10-20 minutes in the VM to keep it from going into suspend mode and to key the gateway online. Any direction to a example VB script I could use as a starting point?

Comment: https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/simulates-printscreen-key-sendkeys.html might give you an idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can perhaps simply use WScript Shell to open up Notepad and send a few keys:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad.exe"
WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"

WshShell.SendKeys "Stay Awake: " & Now
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

This should keep things going. Maybe you can simply Alt-Tab between applications using the same approach:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "&{TAB}"
```